# Form post doesn't post inputs if these inputs are appending in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a formulaire,
Every input type text are sent well as checkbox, radio, textarea, etc..
But I have a part of my input that are appending inside an ng-repeat.
All these inputs are not post so php doesn't see them.
if I make a var_dump in route POST, I won't see these inputs.

My problem is more strange than that because this ng-repeat is inside my form tag.
My form is split in 2 parts, a part between a div in float right and a part between a div in float left.
In the float left part the ng-repeat part appending inputs doesn't work (if I dump my inputs in my post route these inputs aren't appearing).
In the right one, the ng-repeat part appending inputs works well as I want (they exist in my post route and can be saved in my db)!

It's not clear I know but I can't be more clear and I can not share you all my code because of my boss...

This is my ng-repeat part

```
<label for="test" class="article-label-form">Article's Content</label>
<div ng-repeat="core in article['core']">
     <label for="article_core_img_<% $index %>">Section Name</label>
     <input class="article-create-input" type="text" name="core_name[]" ng-model="core['core_name']" />

     <label  for="article_core_img_<% $index %>">Image</label>
     <input class="article-create-input" type="text" name="core_image[]" ng-model="core['core_image']" />

     <label for="article_core_content_<% $index %>">Content</label>
     <textarea id="article_core_content_<% $index %>" name="core_content[]" ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" class="redactor_content" ng-model="core['core_content']"></textarea>

     <label for="article_core_img_<% $index %>">Parallax</label>
     <input class="article-create-input" type="text" id="article_core_img_<% $index %>" ng-model="core['core_parallax']" name="core_parallax[]" />

     <i class="fa fa-minus pointer" ng-show="$index > 0" ng-click="removeCoreElement($index)"></i>                
     <br />
     <i ng-show="$index == article['core'].length - 1" class="fa fa-plus pointer" ng-click="addCoreElement($index)"></i>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your `$_POST` dump? Also, did you check the code inline of the browser to ensure that `$index` is being assigned properly? I've never used the ASP tag setting but don't you still need to echo? Also, there are no PHP wrapper tags for the last two `i` elements. Are you getting any error on the page?

Comment: for the $_POST like I said all of my inputs are shown but there is no 'core_name' => [] and other 'core_...' => []. that's it.
There is no error in console or on the page. No i don't need to.. angular does that stuff.
Like I said everything works when I put this code between my div in float right, but the one in float left no.. And when I'm on the float left part if I take off the "ng-repeat=..." I see my input in my $_POST dump... so I really don't understand anything about that bug..